# problem with getting items from database through intent

Tags: java, android

I developed a vocabulary app that has a Recycler View in main activity and shows two column of database: unit number and Unit name.When I click on each item it goes to another activity called inner page that has 6 text views and it must show other items of that row like word definition unit number spell meaning and part of speech. But unfortunately text views are empty and it shows only one value which is unit number.Please take a look at my codes and tell me what I missed.

Here's my codes:

Main page:

```
public class TabWord extends Fragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private ArrayList<WordItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
private WordTab adapter;
private DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
private Cursor cursor ;

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ViewGroup viewGroup = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_word, container, false);
    recyclerView = viewGroup.findViewById(R.id.recyclerview_word);
    adapter = new WordTab(items, getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    loadDatabase();
    return viewGroup;
}


public void loadDatabase() {

    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    try {
        databaseHelper.checkAndCopyDatabase();
        databaseHelper.openDatabase();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        cursor = databaseHelper.QueryData("select * from ielts");
        if (cursor != null) {
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    WordItem item = new WordItem();
                    item.setUnitName(cursor.getString(2));
                    item.setUnitNumber(cursor.getString(1));
                    items.add(item);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    adapter = new WordTab(items, getActivity());
    adapter.setOnTapListener(new OnTapListener() {
        @Override
        public void OnTapView(int position) {

        }
    });
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}


}
```

Adapter:

```
public class WordTab extends RecyclerView.Adapter<WordTab.ViewHolder> {

public static List<WordItem> wordItems;
private Context context;
private OnTapListener onTapListener;

public WordTab(List<WordItem> wordItems, Context context) {
    this.wordItems = wordItems;
    this.context = context;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.sample_word, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    WordItem wordItem = wordItems.get(position);
    holder.unitNumber.setText(wordItem.getUnitNumber());
    holder.unitName.setText(wordItem.getUnitName());
    holder.cardView.setId(position);
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (onTapListener != null) {
                onTapListener.OnTapView(position);
                int position = v.getId();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, InnerPage.class);
                intent.putExtra("name", "words");
                intent.putExtra("id", position + "");
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return wordItems.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView unitName, unitNumber;
    CardView cardView;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        unitName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unit_name);
        unitNumber = itemView.findViewById(R.id.unit_number);
        cardView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_word);
    }
}

public void setOnTapListener(OnTapListener onTapListener) {
    this.onTapListener = onTapListener;
}
}
```

Model:

```
 public class WordItem {

private int id;
private String unitNumber;
private String unitName;
private String word;
private String phonetic,pos,persian,definition;

public WordItem() {

    this.unitName = unitName;
    this.unitNumber = unitNumber;
    this.word = word;
    this.phonetic = phonetic;
    this.pos = pos;
    this.persian = persian;
    this.definition = definition;
    this.id = id;
}

public String getWord() {
    return word;
}

public void setWord(String word) {
    this.word = word;
}

public String getPhonetic() {
    return phonetic;
}

public void setPhonetic(String phonetic) {
    this.phonetic = phonetic;
}

public String getPos() {
    return pos;
}

public void setPos(String pos) {
    this.pos = pos;
}

public String getPersian() {
    return persian;
}

public void setPersian(String persian) {
    this.persian = persian;
}

public String getDefinition() {
    return definition;
}

public void setDefinition(String definition) {
    this.definition = definition;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUnitNumber() {
    return unitNumber;
}

public void setUnitNumber(String unitNumber) {
    this.unitNumber = unitNumber;
}

public String getUnitName() {
    return unitName;
}

public void setUnitName(String unitName) {
    this.unitName = unitName;
}
```

}

Inner Page:

```
public class InnerPage extends AppCompatActivity {

private int id;
private String unitNumber,word,phonetic,pos,persian,definition;
private TextView unitTxt,wordTxt,phoneticTxt,posTxt,persianTxt,definitionTxt;
private int layoutId;
private String pageName;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.inner_page);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        layoutId = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("id"));
        pageName = extras.getString("name");

        if (pageName.equals("words")){
            id = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getId();
            unitNumber = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getUnitNumber();
            word = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getWord();
            phonetic = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getPhonetic();
            pos = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getPos();
            persian = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getPersian();
            definition = WordTab.wordItems.get(layoutId).getDefinition();
        }
    }

    unitTxt = findViewById(R.id.unit);
    wordTxt = findViewById(R.id.word);
    phoneticTxt = findViewById(R.id.phonetic);
    posTxt = findViewById(R.id.txtSpell);
    persianTxt = findViewById(R.id.farMean);
    definitionTxt = findViewById(R.id.definition);

    unitTxt.setText(unitNumber);
    wordTxt.setText(word);
    phoneticTxt.setText(phonetic);
    posTxt.setText(pos);
    persianTxt.setText(persian);
    definitionTxt.setText(definition);

}
}
```

Comment: Anyone to answer ??

Comment: I believe the best way to send `WordItem` data to `InnerPage` would be by making `WordItem` implement `Parcelable`. By doing that you can put the `wordItem` object as an extra in the intent you're creating in `holder.cardView`'s `onClick` .